# Is there anything on iOS that would cause your mail pulls to be set to manual?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app

I had a user come in where I work, and she said that she didn't get emails on her iPhone 4; she was running iOS7.  I have an iPhone 5c, and I failed to receive emails around 8:30 PM today.

Her issue was that in her settings her mail had been set to only update manually.  When I checked my phone, mine had also been set to manual.  They're both phones that have been setup recently, is that the default setting?  Or does it get set when it is placed on do not disturb?  I'm really concerned about this because both of us missed important emails.

Comment: DnD doesn't seem to set it to manual, just checked. idk what the initial setup would be, I set mine up too long ago to remember. Only IMAP will push, btw, POP will only fetch, when you launch the mail app, which is, in effect 'manual'

Comment: What does DnD stand for?

Comment: Do Not Disturb.

Comment: We're using Office 365 for mail if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I use Office 365 here too, through BT, not as a full subscription - mine is POP3, not IMAP. It cannot push emails to the phone, it will only fetch when you launch the mail app. Check… Settings > Mail, contacts.. > Fetch New Data - any accounts there that say Fetch can only get email when you launch Mail; any that say Push [iCloud/me.com for example] can Push mail to you at all times.